# Javascript search engine, limit search results

Tags: javascript, search

I'm new to JavaScript and I want to limit the search results to 10.
www.bikinituna.com/search/
for example, type set in the search box and you will get all of the results available
I only want a maximum of 10 results to display.

here is the JavaScript:

FILE JSE_FORM:

```
var results_location = "results.html";

function search_form(jse_Form) {
    if (jse_Form.d.value.length > 0) {
            document.cookie = "d=" + escape(jse_Form.d.value);
        window.location = results_location;
    }
}
```

FILE JSE_SEARCH:

```
var include_num = 1;
var bold = 0;
var s = new Array();
s[0] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/padmalakshmi/set1/^/celebs/padmalakshmi/set1/^Padma Lakshmi [August 1, 2013]^padma, lakshmi";
s[1] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/josieconseco/set1/^/celebs/josieconseco/set1/^Josie Conseco [August 2, 2013]^josie, conseco";
s[2] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/debbieotoole/set1/^/celebs/debbieotoole/set1/^Debbie O'Toole [August 3, 2013]^debbie, otoole";
s[3] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/rihanna/set1/^/celebs/rihanna/set1/^Rihanna [August 4, 2013]^rihanna";
s[4] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/kourtneykardashian/set1/^/celebs/kourtneykardashian/set1/^Kourtney Kardashian [August 5, 2013]^kourtney, kardashian";
s[5] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/cassieventura/set1/^/celebs/cassieventura/set1/^Cassie Ventura [August 6, 2013]^cassie, ventura";
s[6] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/jillmartin/set1/^/celebs/jillmartin/set1/^Jill Martin [August 7, 2013]^jill, martin";
s[7] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/courtneystodden/set1/^/celebs/courtneystodden/set1/^Courtney Stodden [August 8, 2013]^courtney, stodden";
s[8] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/irinashayk/set1/^/celebs/irinashayk/set1/^Irina Shayk [August 9, 2013]^irina, shayk";
s[9] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/candiceswanepoel/set1/^/celebs/candiceswanepoel/set1/^Candice Swanepoel [August 10, 2013]^candice, swanepoel";
s[10] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/evalongoria/set1/^/celebs/evalongoria/set1/^Eva Longoria [August 11, 2013]^eva, longoria";
s[11] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/oliviawilde/set1/^/celebs/oliviawilde/set1/^Olivia Wilde [August 12, 2013]^olivia, wilde";
s[12] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/kristymaclaren/set1/^/celebs/kristymaclaren/set1/^Kristy MacLaren [August 13, 2013]^kristy, maclaren";
s[13] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/doutzenkroes/set1/^/celebs/doutzenkroes/set1/^Doutzen Kroes [August 14, 2013]^doutzen, kroes";
s[14] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/gerihalliwell/set1/^/celebs/gerihalliwell/set1/^Geri Halliwell [August 15, 2013]^geri, halliwell";
s[15] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/kellybrook/set1/^/celebs/kellybrook/set1/^Kelly Brook [August 16, 2013]^kelly, brook";
s[16] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/dianavickers/set1/^/celebs/dianavickers/set1/^Diana Vickers [August 17, 2013]^diana, vickers";
s[17] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/bethennyfrankel/set1/^/celebs/bethennyfrankel/set1/^Bethenny Frankel [August 18, 2013]^bethenny, frankel";
s[18] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/jennifernicolelee/set1/^/celebs/jennifernicolelee/set1/^Jennifer Nicole Lee [August 19, 2013]^jennifer, nicole, lee";
s[19] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/lolaponce/set1/^/celebs/lolaponce/set1/^Lola Ponce [August 20, 2013]^lola, ponce";
s[20] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/gabriellereece/set1/^/celebs/gabriellereece/set1/^Gabrielle Reece [August 21, 2013]^gabrielle, reece";
s[21] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/claudiaromani/set1/^/celebs/claudiaromani/set1/^Claudia Romani [August 22, 2013]^claudia, romani";
s[22] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/suzannequast/set1/^/celebs/suzannequast/set1/^Suzanne Quast [August 23, 2013]^suzanne, quast";
s[23] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/mileycyrus/set1/^/celebs/mileycyrus/set1/^Miley Cyrus [August 24, 2013]^miley, cyrus";
s[24] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/charismacarpenter/set1/^/celebs/charismacarpenter/set1/^Charisma Carpenter [August 25, 2013]^charisma, carpenter";
s[25] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/ilaryblasi/set1/^/celebs/ilaryblasi/set1/^Ilary Blasi [August 26, 2013]^ilary, blasi";
s[26] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/alessandraambrosio/set1/^/celebs/alessandraambrosio/set1/^Alessandra Ambrosio [August 27, 2013]^alessandra, ambrosio";
s[27] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/anaiszanotti/set1/^/celebs/anaiszanotti/set1/^Anais Zanotti [August 28, 2013]^anais, zanotti";
s[28] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/lindsaylohan/set1/^/celebs/lindsaylohan/set1/^Lindsay Lohan [August 29, 2013]^lindsay, lohan";
s[29] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/carmenortega/set1/^/celebs/carmenortega/set1/^Carmen Ortega [August 30, 2013]^carmen, ortega";
s[30] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/emmanuellechriqui/set1/^/celebs/emmanuellechriqui/set1/^Emmanuelle Chriqui [August 31, 2013]^emmanuelle, chriqui";
s[31] = "bikinituna.com/celebs/vanessahudgens/set1/^/celebs/vanessahudgens/set1/^Vanessa Hudgens [August 2013 Bonus]^vanessa, hudgens";

var cookies = document.cookie;
var p = cookies.indexOf("d=");

if (p != -1) {
    var st = p + 2;
    var en = cookies.indexOf(";", st);
    if (en == -1) {
    en = cookies.length;
    }
    var d = cookies.substring(st, en);
    d = unescape(d);
}
var od = d;
var m = 0;
if (d.charAt(0) == '"' && d.charAt(d.length - 1) == '"') {
    m = 1;
}

var r = new Array();
var co = 0;

if (m == 0) {
var woin = new Array();
var w = d.split(" ");
for (var a = 0; a < w.length; a++) {
    woin[a] = 0;
    if (w[a].charAt(0) == '-') {
        woin[a] = 1;
    }
}
for (var a = 0; a < w.length; a++) {
    w[a] = w[a].replace(/^\-|^\+/gi, "");
}
a = 0;
for (var c = 0; c < s.length; c++) {
    pa = 0;
    nh = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < woin.length; i++) {
        if (woin[i] == 0) {
            nh++;
            var pat = new RegExp(w[i], "i");
            var rn = s[c].search(pat);
            if (rn >= 0) {
                pa++;
            } else {
                pa = 0;
            }
        }
        if (woin[i] == 1) {
            var pat = new RegExp(w[i], "i");
            var rn = s[c].search(pat);
            if (rn >= 0) {
                pa = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if (pa == nh) {
        r[a] = s[c];
        a++;
    }
}
co = a;
}

if (m == 1) {
d = d.replace(/"/gi, "");
var a = 0;
var pat = new RegExp(d, "i");
for (var c = 0; c < s.length; c++) {
    var rn = s[c].search(pat);
    if (rn >= 0) {
        r[a] = s[c];
        a++;
    }
}
co = a;

}


function return_query() {
document.jse_Form.d.value = od;
}

function num_jse() {
document.write(co);
}

function out_jse() {
if (co == 0) {
    document.write('Your search did not match any models.', '<br><br>');
    return;
}
for (var a = 0; a < r.length; a++) {
    var os = r[a].split("^");
    if (bold == 1 && m == 1) {
        var br = "<b>" + d + "</b>";
        os[2] = os[2].replace(pat, br);
    }
    if (include_num == 1) {
        document.write(os[2], '<br>', '<a href="', os[1], '">', os[0], '</a><br><br>');
    } else {
        document.write('<a href="', os[1], '">', os[0], '</a><br>', os[2]);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to limit the loops, replace each

```
r.length
```

with

```
Math.min(r.length,10)
```

Comment: I did that but it only shows results within the 10 listed. For example if you search for Claudia after making the changes you suggested, it returns no results.

Comment: @BikiniTuna Correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't that only limit what is going to be searched, not the amount of total results? Example: The first 10 items don't match the query so nothing is returned...

Comment: Yes, you are right, not s.length, r.length needs to get replaced

Comment: Another question: How do you make a text link where when clicked, it performs the search? (without using the search box)

Comment: you set the cookie d with your search word and than navigate to the result html page, same as done above.

Comment: I get the gist of what you mean, but I don't understand how to write it.

Comment: Something like this? <a href="/search/results.html" onclick="search_form(jse_Form);">Kim Kardashian</a>

Comment: That should work <a href="#" onclick="function() {document.cookie = "d="+escape('Kardashian');
        window.location = '/search/results.html';}()">Kardashian</a>

Comment: I tried that, nothing happened. I played around with the code too, but nothing worked.

Comment: I played around with it and I got this to work: <a href="/search/results.html" onclick="search_form(jse_Form); document.cookie = 'd='+escape('Kim Kardashian');">Kim Kardashian</a>